# For built-in functions that take nvarchar as a parameter, if the supplied value is varchar, the value is still converted to nvarchar(4000)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The MS documentation about [differences between compatibility level 80 and lLevel 90](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510680(v=sql.105)#remarks) is saying about compatibility level 90:

> "For built-in functions that take nvarchar as a parameter, if the supplied value is varchar, the value is still converted to nvarchar(4000). However, if a larger value is passed, SQL Server 2008 generates an error."

But, when I try it in SQL Server 2008 R2, it is always silently truncated:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @SQL = REPLICATE(N'A', 9000) -- It's return 4000

SELECT LEN(@SQL)
```

Comment: Both of the database editions you mention are out of support for some time now. Mixing up `varchar` and `nvarchar` fields is a problem in itself though. If you have such code, you need to fix it, not try to bypass the problem by increasing column values.

Comment: What's your *actual* problem? The maximum length is 8000 for varchar and 4000 for nvarchar. `REPLACE` works as expected in each case and produces the maximum allowed string, eg `select len(REPLICATE('A',9000))` will produce a 8000-long string.

Comment: DId you try to generate a dynamic SQL statement that exceeded the 4000 character limit? In that case, you should fix the query or not use dynamic SQL in the first place. This is what an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) looks like - you have a problem X and thing that Y is the solution (in this case create a query by string concatenation). When that fails you ask about Y (the string size limit), not the original problem X. Most likely you need a different schema, to break apart that huge query into views or use functions.

Comment: I am trying return error when nvarchar large than 4000.I try both DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) and DECLARE VARCHAR(4000), it always return 4000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single character literal string is still an `nvarchar` and is **not** declared as a `MAX`. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLICATE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to the appropriate large-value data type.

You therefore have a `nvarchar(1)` which is replicated 9,000 times. Once you have 4,000 characters you have 8,000 bytes, and so the limit is reached. If you want 8,000 characters you would need to do this:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000);

SET @SQL = REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), N'A'), 9000); 

SELECT LEN(@SQL); --Returns 8,000
```

*Edit: The above also returns a truncated value, without error, as this is also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#truncating-and-rounding-results):*

> When converting character or binary expressions (binary, char, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or varchar) to an expression of a different data type, **the conversion operation could truncate the output data, only partially display the output data**, or return an error. These cases will occur if the result is too short to display. **Conversions to binary, char, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or varchar are truncated**, except for the conversions shown in the following table.

Comment: It is silently truncated and not return error if a larger value is passed, isn't it?

Comment: It will not error, no @NganMai, as this is documented behaviour.

Comment: This is also true for `CONVERT`, @NganMai .

Comment: If this answered your question @NganMai, then please mark it as the solution, so that future readers with the same question know it (the answer) was helpful. Thanks.